# Looking for SMTP server for use with windows

Tags: php, windows, apache, smtp

I'm looking for an SMTP server that I can setup on a windows machine:

- It needs to be lightweight, not loads of security settings
- I only need to send email not receive it
- Its needs to be able to send email from anonymous users

The reason is that I've installed Apache and PHP on a windows machine and want an SMTP server to route mails through, I plan on using this windows [sendmail.exe](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) which I have used before and works great.

Last time I did this I used sendmail.exe and [Stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org) and used a gmail address, but I can't do that this time, needs to be sent from localhost.

Comment: Be sure to keep ISP blocks in mind; you're probably already familiar with this if you've done the stunnel/gmail route before. But should port 25 seem magically unavailable, head on over to 587 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SMTP server integrated in IIS, you could also go for smaller mail servers like http://www.xmailserver.org/ or http://www.mailenable.com/

Answer (score 1):

Too bad, stunnel/gmail is great and I've used it a ton for test environments.

Two great alternatives are to install [exim via Cygwin](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Microsoft_Windows/WINDOWS_4.shtml#Exim%20-%20%28as%20part%20of%20Cygwin%29), or to [use IIS as an SMTP server](http://www.ehow.com/how_4489548_set-up-smtp-server-windows.html).

I have personally used the first with success. I have never tried IIS although I know this is a viable solution for some.